# DataContract won't deserialize Id DataMember

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

When using the DataContract serializer, it fails to deserialize the `Id` value as in the below sample:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public class Program
{
    private const string SAMPLE_VALIDATION_RESULT_XML = @"    <ValidationResult>
      <Message>The FooBar record has duplicate key values.</Message>
      <Id>Microsoft.LightSwitch.EntityObject.DuplicateKey</Id>
      <Target>http://localhost:55815/ApplicationData.svc/FooBar(0)</Target>
    </ValidationResult>";

    [DataContract(Name = "ValidationResult", Namespace = "")]
    public class ValidationResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Target { get; set; }
    }


    public static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(SAMPLE_VALIDATION_RESULT_XML);
        using (var reader = doc.CreateReader())
        {
            reader.MoveToContent();
            var res = (new DataContractSerializer(typeof(ValidationResult))).ReadObject(reader) as ValidationResult;
            Console.WriteLine($"res.Id = \"{res.Id}\", expected \"Microsoft.LightSwitch.EntityObject.DuplicateKey\"");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing it's to do with the referential integrity features, but I only found one option to disable that (on the DataContractSerializer), and it didn't affect the outcome.

I can't change the name of the `Id` field, as it's a third-party API, so how can I access that value?

Comment: This code `ReadObject(reader) as ValidationResult` is considered bad form. Since you know that it will always be a `ValidationResult`, you should use an explicit cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify order of members

```
[DataContract(Name = "ValidationResult", Namespace = "")]
public class ValidationResult
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Target { get; set; }
}
```

Without specifying an order, the `DataContractSerializer` expects the members will be in alphabetical order. See [Basic rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is obvious that the order established by the service provider. So you must specify it.

Comment: That seems a bit fragile - I don't know for sure that the API provider will always return them in the right order.

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. I'm surprised that they added that restriction.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead. The XmlSerializer doesn't care about order.

```
var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ValidationResult));
var res = (ValidationResult)xml.Deserialize(reader);
```

Comment: I'll probably use this approach, however, I've marked the other as the answer because it answers the implicit question ("why doesn't this work?").

Comment: I would do the same. My answer, however useful, is a work-around.